# Can't seem to call the pre_process function, comes up with undefined name

Tags: python, function, project

```
    def removeStopWords(words):
        return list(set([w for w in words if not w in sw.words('english')]))

    def pre_process(x_user):
        words = []
        with open("words.txt",'r') as data_file:
            textdata = data_file.readlines()
        for line in textdata:    
            try:
                words.append(line.split()[0].lower())
            except:
                pass    
            completed_words = removeStopWords(words)
            print(completed_words)
             
       
    def GButton_6_command(self):

        x_user = root.entry.get()
        pr = pre_process
        pr.user_words(x_user)
        model = pkl.load(open('Training_model.pkl', 'rb'))
        pred = model.predict(pr.user_words)
        print(pred)
```

Code is meant to take user input and apply ML program to user input.
The above is the gui, which works but when i try to call the pre_process,
it classifies it as undefined name and i'm just trying to figure out why.

Comment: What is the _exact_ error? There are a number of things wrong. `pr = pre_process` doesn't call the function, you need to do `pre_process(...)` with the parenthesis and the function arguments `(...)`, just like how you called `removeStopWords(words)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed mistake at `pr = pre_process`, You have just stored the refrence to the function, to call the function you have to add opening and closing parenthesis after the function name, which in your case should be `pr = pre_process()`.

**I think you are using classes, so you can use `self.pre_process()`**

Also i dont recommed you to take function variable value like this `pr.user_words(x_user)`, I would suggest you to use `return` statement in your function to return the value to the variable from which you have called the function.